# ChartJs dimensions on toBase64Image()

Tags: charts, chart.js

Currently I'm showing a single chart on my website in a responsive div, therefore it gets smaller as the screen width is decreased. My problem is: I'm saving an image of this chart but I need it to be always 700x400 even if my screen is 320x___.

```
lineChart.toBase64Image();
```

Is it possible?